# Add AIR 2 to FB4?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, beta, air2

I downloaded and installed FB4 beta 2. I want to try out some of the new AIR 2 beta features, but AIR 2 is not packed with FB4 by default, how can I set this up?

Thanks!

(Also if possible I still want to be able to use FB3+AIR1 for regular projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows

Go to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder Beta 2\sdks\4.0.0

And duplicate the 4.0.0 folder and rename the new copy to AIR 2.0

Download the AIR 2 beta.
Drop it in:
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder Beta 2\sdks\AIR 2.0

Within FB4 go to Window>Preferences>Flash Builder>Installed Flex SDKs

Click Add and navigate to the new folder you added.

It will ask you to give the new SDK a name (name it something like AIR 2)

Now create a new Flex project and choose AIR 2 (or whatever name you gave it) from the SDK drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the air 2.0 sdk http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air2.html and then follow the instructions in the [release notes](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/AIR_2:Release_Notes).

The installation of the sdk is not global, so you will have to choose which flex sdks you want to install it in.

If you are installing on a Mac you will want to look at this [post](http://mchristoff.com/2009/12/installing-the-adobe-air-2-beta-sdk-on-os-x/)